# How to avoid import Ember in every file in ember-cli project

Tags: ember-cli

Our team recently migrate from Ember App Kit to Ember-cli, one issue is we need to explicitly put `import Ember from 'ember';` in almost every file. Is there a recommend way to avoid this? Since we are write an Ember project, Ember is being used in almost every file, IMO it is like you won't need to `import System` in Java

Comment: tl;dr modules are meant to be isolated, you have to import the modules you use. This isn't java.

Comment: but when you include non modular library in brocfile.js you didn't include them neither

Comment: You mean bower components?

Comment: yeah like those libraries installed via bower